# Setting Features-Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I am trying "learning by example" which was given in the uima ruta documentation.I have tried how to define and assign a relation of employment, by storing the given annotations as feature values.But I got error messages.I'm not clear in that concept can explain me in detail.

```
DECLARE Annotation EmplRelation 
(Employee employeeRef, Employer employerRef);
Sentence{CONTAINS(EmploymentIndicator) -> CREATE(EmplRelation,"employeeRef" = Employee, "employerRef" = Employer)};
e1:Employer # EmploymentIndicator # e2:Employee) {-> EmplRelation, EmplRelation.employeeRef=e2, EmplRelation.employerRef=e1};
```

Comment: What does the error message say? Is that the complete script? If yes, then you need to declare the other types: Employer, EmploymentIndicator, Employee and Sentence. And you need annotations of these types if the two rules should do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assuming what the mentioned error messages could be: The script in the question is not complete. The section "learning by example" does not contain always complete scripts but builts upon previous examples. A complete and running script for this example could look like (for an input text like "Peter works for Frank."):

```
DECLARE Employee, Employer, EmploymentIndicator, Sentence;
DECLARE EmplRelation (Employee employeeRef, Employer employerRef);

// create some dummy annotations to work on
"Peter" -> Employee;
"Frank" -> Employer;
"works for" -> EmploymentIndicator;
(# PERIOD){-> Sentence};

// the actual rules
Sentence{CONTAINS(EmploymentIndicator) -> CREATE(EmplRelation,"employeeRef" = Employee, "employerRef" = Employer)};
(e1:Employee # EmploymentIndicator # e2:Employer) {-> EmplRelation, EmplRelation.employeeRef=e1, EmplRelation.employerRef=e2};
```

Please mind that I modified the last rule so that it works on the minimal example.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*